# How to test an if statement from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have a function which stores the position of different competitors in a list and then appends the list whenever the competitors have to move on the board. The board location is defined as (horizontaland vertical are the x,y size of each rectangle in the grid):

```
    positions = [
    [-3*HORIZONTAL, 3*VERTICAL, 'A', 7],
    [3*HORIZONTAL, 3*VERTICAL, 'G', 7],
    [-3*HORIZONTAL, -3*VERTICAL, 'A', 1],
    [3*HORIZONTAL, -3*VERTICAL, 'G', 1]
]

used = [  
    [('A', 7)],
    [('G', 7)],
    [('A', 1)],
    [('G', 1)]
]
```

I am wondering if someone could explain how I can test for the first competitor to reach the middle grid position on the board ('D', 4) and then draw it in a seperate legend stating "the winner is (competitor)". I already have the drawing function completed.

```
#if competitor reaches position [D],[4] 
#draw  competitor at predetermined cordinates (x,y)
#add text above to state the winner is
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you haven't said anything about the relation of competitor and moves used i am sharing something according to my understanding from the question. feel free to say if its not what u are trying to do.

```
used = [  
    [('A', 7)],
    [('G', 7)],
    [('A', 1)],
    [('G', 1)]
]
if used[-1]==[('D', 4)]:
    competitor=#code to find who done the last move
    print('the winner is {}',competitor)
```

you have all moves inside the list and i believe that these are added in iterative steps. so u can just check the last entry to the list and find the competitor name who used it.